# mypy error: error: Value of type "Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]" is not indexable

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, static-code-analysis

I have a small function which I've typohinted, but I get a mypy error. I looked it up and found some suggestions regarding casting and adding assertion but they don't help either.
I'm using `mypy==0.812` and Python 3.6. Any hints on how to fix this would help.

```
error: Value of type "Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]" is not indexable
```

This is the function:

```
from typing import Union
from datetime import datetime

def _get_number(my_dict: Union[dict, None], relevant_key: Union[str, None]) -> int:
    if my_dict is None:
        return 0
    else:
        # my_dict: dict = cast(dict, my_dict) # adding this didn't help with the mypy error
        # assert isinstance(my_dict, dict) # adding this didn't help with the mypy error
        sorted_keys = sorted(
            my_dict,
            key=lambda k: datetime.strptime(my_dict[k], "%H:%M").time(),
        )
        return sorted_keys.index(relevant_key)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that although `my_dict` is known to be a dictionary where the lambda is declared, MyPy is not smart enough to know it will still be a dictionary when the lambda is called. In the general case, MyPy is correct to label this as an error:

```py
def test(d: Optional[dict]) -> None:
    if d is not None:
        # d is definitely a dict where the lambda is declared
        f = lambda: print(d['foo'])
        d = None
        # now d is None when the lambda is called
        f()
```

The difference between your code and this example is that there is no opportunity for `my_dict` to become `None` in between the lambda being declared and it being called, because `sorted` calls the lambda immediately and then discards it. But MyPy doesn't know that, so it conservatively labels your code with the same error.

The solution is to use a variable of type `dict` instead of `Optional[dict]`. You can achieve this simply by declaring a new variable like `my_actual_dict: dict = my_dict` just after checking that `my_dict` isn't `None`, and then use `my_actual_dict` in the lambda. Since `my_actual_dict` has the static type `dict`, MyPy knows it can't be assigned the value `None` after the lambda is declared.

Answer (score 0):

While @kaya3 is correct, it quite defeats the use of a lambda function to have to specify all of this just to satisfy type checking.  I would offer the alternative to just let mypy skip this line with an ignore pragma.

```
sorted_keys = sorted(
            my_dict,
            key=lambda k: datetime.strptime(my_dict[k], "%H:%M").time(),
        ) #type: ignore
```